# SQL Server 2008 Trace column filters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I wanna make a trace to monitoring a stored procedure ,and in SQL Server Profiler at Events Selection  I have SP:Stmt Completed SP:Stmt Starting SP:Starting SP:Completed and at ->Edit Filter what to choose?

Duration,EndTIme,CPU..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could track the text and look for the stored procedure name.

[image]